# Callback URL for the API Response Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, callback

I am building a code editor using the [Hackerearth API](https://www.hackerearth.com/docs/wiki/developers/v3/).I have made the code  to send a asynchronous API Request as it would speed up performance and reduce waiting time.

I referred their [docs](https://www.hackerearth.com/docs/wiki/developers/v3/) about sending an async request.I need to specify a callback url.Currently my project is running locally.**So I couldn't figure out how to specify the callback URL and render out the Response from that callback URL**.The logic to process the response received at the callback url is also specified in their docs.

```
def compileCode(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        source = request.POST.get('source')
        lang = request.POST.get('lang')
        client_secret = settings.CLIENT_SECRET
        data = {
           "client_secret": client_secret,
           "async": 1,
           'id': 123,        
           'callback': **what to do here**,
           "source": source,
           "lang": lang,
        }
        res = requests.post(RUN_URL, data=data)
        return JsonResponse(res.json(), safe=False)        
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Code to process the Response from the callback URL

```
def api_response(request):
   payload = request.POST.get('payload', '')
   payload = json.loads(payload)
   run_status = payload.get('run_status')
   o = run_status['output']
   return HttpResponse('API Response Recieved!')
```

Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

A callback URL "calls back" a web address rather than a bit of code and it can be invoked by API method, you can call after it's done. That URL can be anything. It doesn't have to be a static URL. Often it is a script to perform certain functions.

> As here you don't need to perform anything after receiving results.

You don't need to pass the `callback url`, it will work even without it.

I made it work by just passing by below code.

```
RUN_URL = "https://api.hackerearth.com/v3/code/run/"
CLIENT_SECRET = 'your-client-secret-from-hackerearth'

data = {
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'async': 1,
    'source': source,
    'lang': lang,
}

r = requests.post(RUN_URL, data=data)
```

Comment: What if I need to send an asynchronous request to the API? At that time what should be the callback url

Comment: "If you can migrate to async version of the version 3 code API, then we can assure you the uptime of code evaluation. We do not maintain version 2 API and synchronous version of version 3 API." --> I read this about Hackerearth API.So help me out in making a asynchronous request.

Comment: Also now the API is not responding properly.It sends only "{'code_id': 'f97424E', 'run_status': {'status_detail': 'Correct the compilation/syntax errors.', 'status': 'CE'}, 'compile_status': 'Error code: 1200}
" for any request sent. :(

Comment: The code is fine. We are using `asynchronous` V3 api. I think 1200 error is error on their side and not on yours. Just check after some time it will be resolved.

Comment: If need to use `asynchronous` v3 api, then shouldn't be aync be set to 1 in the payload data?

Comment: Check their docs.If need to send asynchronous request, then async should be set to 1 and callbackURL , id should be the required params.